# On AWS, can we setup the loadbalancer to multicast?

Tags: amazon-web-services, multicast

I need to figure out the easiest way to multicast a request that is going from SOURCE to DEST1 to instead go from SOURCE to DEST1 and DEST2.  I have a load balancer getting hit with the SOURCE requests first, and it sends it to DEST 1.  Is there a way to have it multicast to DEST1 and DEST2?  (Essentially, not load balancing at all.)

I'm in AWS EC2.  Just need an easy way to do this.  I can install custom code on the DEST1 server to forward requests to DEST2 OR I can have something multicast in front of both the servers.

Comment: what kind of requests are they?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native AWS service that will do this. You can use a variety of reverse proxy tools. For example you can use the experimental [iptables ROUTE target](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/patch-o-matic/pom-external.html#pom-external-ROUTE) or something like this [duplicator](https://github.com/agnoster/duplicator) project. There are many ways to do it, but you'll need to roll your own solution.